# Trigger Macro only when Cell Value is Increased

Tags: excel, vba

its me....again. I am currently trying to have a Macro trigger whenever a specific cell increases on a specific sheet.

After many attempts I have been able to get the Macro to trigger when the cell is changed (increasing or decreasing) but I cannot figure out a way to have this Macro trigger only when the specified cell increases in value.

I have tried to use simple Worksheet_Change with an If Then statement that calls the Macro when the cell value is changed. Again I can't get this to trigger only when the cell increases. Not sure it is possible or if I am even thinking about this is in the right way.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address "Range" Then
    Call MyMacro

End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help in advance. This would be really neat and save alot of manual clicking around.

---

Here is the functioning Macro that I want to trigger when certain text is entered into a range.

```
Sub Auto_Print_Yellow_Caution()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets("Saver").Shapes("Group 6").Copy
    Sheets("Main").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Select
    
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I already have my Workbook set up to track these words/phrases and return either a TRUE or FALSE value. If TRUE the associated Order Number is Printed into a Cell and a COUNTIFS formula is used to keep track of how many orders meet the TRUE condition. That number is then used to keep track of how many total of those orders there are. That works using the following

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Completed",Main!G7)),TRUE)
-**looks for specific word and returns TRUE**

=IF(T3=TRUE,Main!A7,"")
-**Returns order number**

=IF(COUNTIF($U3:$U$200,"?*")<ROW(U3)-2,"",INDEX(U:U,SMALL(IF(U$2:U$200<>"",ROW(U$2:U$200)),ROWS(U$2:U3))))
-**Sorts order numbers into list**

=COUNTIF(T2:T135,TRUE)
-**Counts number of orders**

Hopefully this adds context to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Could you share a working code? `If Target.Address  "Range" Then` is invalid. Also, the code might depend on what the `MyMacro` procedure does. Could you share its code, too?

Comment: I added additional info to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

This will hopefully get you on the right track. As per your question it assumes this is required for a single cell only (and in this example code, that cell is B2). The trick is to store the new value, 'undo' the change, grab the old value, reverse the 'undo' by replacing the new value. Then you can test if the values are numbers and, if so, test if the new number is greater than the old number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim newValue As Variant, oldValue As Variant
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 2 Or Target.Row <> 2 Then Exit Sub ' example is using cell B2
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newValue = Target.Value2
    Application.Undo
    oldValue = Target.Value2
    Target.Value2 = newValue
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If IsNumeric(oldValue) And IsNumeric(newValue) Then
        If CDbl(newValue) > CDbl(oldValue) Then
            Call MyMacro
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like this should work but I can't seem to get the Macro to trigger.

Comment: So the code, as it stands, will only call `MyMacro` when the code is placed in the relevant Sheet module (eg 'Sheet1'), when the change is to cell B2, and when B2 already contains a number and a larger number is added to it. Also, events must be enabled. Suggest changing your `MyMacro` Sub to just simply log something to the Immediate window (eg `Debug.Print "Hello"`) to test whether it is really being called.

Comment: Apologies, what do you mean by events must be enabled? I would insert Application.EnableEvents = True somewhere? And if so where would I put it?

Comment: I guess my point was that if you switch off events (eg by using `Application.EnableEvents = False` somewhere else in your code) then the `Worksheet_Change` event won't be triggered. If you have no code that switches events off then okay. However, as an Excel-wide setting, any code anywhere (eg in other Workbooks, AddIns etc) can switch events off for all code. You can test whether events are currently enabled by typing `?Application.EnableEvents` in the Immediate window ... True is enabled.

Comment: Okay I got what you were saying now. I checked and it says events are enabled but I still can't get the macro to trigger. I moved the code to the active sheet. I changed the cell to the one that has the number in it. Maybe I'll try to look into a different method of triggering a macro.

Comment: Yes, the code must be in the 'code behind' of the Sheet that the specific cell is in eg if the cell to be monitored is in Sheet1 then this code must be in the Sheet1 module. I'd suggest you add a `Debug.Print Now, "Got to this line!"` statement to the code to see if it is being triggered. Initially put this statement in a new line immediately after the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` line. If you see output in the Immediate window, keep moving it down through the `Sub` to work out which lines are running or not.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some logic I can think of,  you  need to have a helper cell  to store  previous data and compare if it increased. In   this sample my  **helper  cell is B1** and the  cell I want  to  **track is  A1**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KCells      As Range
    Set KCells = Sheet10.Range("A1")' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then  'cause an alert when they are changed.
        If Sheet10.Range("B1").Value < Sheet10.Range("A1").Value Then
            MsgBox "Replace this to call macro"
            Sheet10.Range("B1").Value = Sheet10.Range("A1").Value 'this is  to save the current data incase you change it later.
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I may be a bit on the dumb side but does that helper cell just need to be a blank cell on the same worksheet?

Comment: Could not get this one to work for what I am trying to do. I will reiterate I am very new to VBA and I don't always look at things with the right logic.